# Automating CSV Column Transfer Between ClipMyDeals and Affiliate Network Files

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the ClipMyDeals WordPress theme, and I need to transfer specific CSV columns from one file, which adheres to the correct format accepted by the ClipMyDeals theme, to import products. The product details I want to copy are sourced from an affiliate network providing product details in a CSV file. However, the affiliate network's CSV file contains many unnecessary columns that are not required by ClipMyDeals. I need assistance in copying the essential columns from the affiliate network's product CSV file to the ClipMyDeals CSV file. I have attached sample data for both files, with the ClipMyDeals CSV file and the product CSV file from the affiliate network named "produkter-partnerid49589-Airfryers.no

The expected outcome was a seamless integration of the essential columns from the affiliate network file into the existing ClipMyDeals CSV file, providing a consolidated dataset ready for importing products.

Answer (score 0):

If there are extra columns not required by your theme, then you can definitely delete those from CSV before uploading the CSV.

Every theme provides support forum for people with problems or questions regarding the theme. Reach out their website and ask the steps involved in asking queries to the support team. I think they will help you with the solution for the problems that you are facing.